# CSV header file in loop

Tags: php, loops, csv, header

I have a CSV file where the sales data is given by the date header and ID is the seller ID. So I want to generate the file where I take the information from the CSV and it prints in the following way :

**ID :65
date:1/22/20
items-1**

**ID :65
date:1/23/20
items-2**

and so on..... and finishing with

**ID :333
date:1/26/20
items-3**

the above will be in a loop for whatever the dates are.

[image: table]

I am using the following code :

```
<?php
$counter=0;
$fileName="test1.csv";
$file=fopen($fileName, "r");    
fgetcsv($file); 

while (($column = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) { 
$counter++;    
// assigning csv column to a variable
$ID=$column[0];
$Dates=$column[1];
$values=$column[2];                     

echo $ID;
echo $Dates;
echo $values ;
}?>
```

to get the columns but I am not able to fetch the way that it gets the left column and then goes to the right column and takes header info and the associated value in the right. All I get the is columns in column-wise and row after a row which does not fit the way I am wanting it.

Comment: since you do have to read the file line by line, you are reading row by row, that's mandatory. I don't see how you can do otherwise with a text file. If you have to read column by column because of some logic here, you'll have to read the file in an appropriate in-memory structure, and then read it the way you want. Or you can asked to have the file sent to you with columns and rows permuted

Comment: I wanted to read the column and row together to fetch it up, down or sideways inside a loop or multiple loops, but not understanding how.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, you are only dealing with the first item in each row.  This code stores the headers (`$headers`) and when reading each row it uses `array_combine()` to add the dates to each value.

It then removes the id of the start of the row and stores it.  Then loops over the remaining data and displays it item by item...

```
$file=fopen($fileName, "r");
$headers = fgetcsv($file);

while (($row = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $counter++;
    $rowData = array_combine($headers, $row);

    $id = array_shift($rowData);
    foreach ( $rowData as $date => $value ) {
        echo "ID :{$id} date:{$date} items-{$value}".PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```